# Continuity domain for momentum operator

Tags: hilbert-spaces, differential-operators

The momentum operator in one dimension in quantum mechanics is $P=-i\frac{d}{dx}$ (with $\hbar=1$). Consider it as an operator on $L_2(0,2\pi)$, the space of square-integrable functions on $(0,2\pi)$. It isn't continuous in fact if I consider the sequence
$$
g_n(x)=\frac{e^{inx}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}
$$
it's a Cauchy sequence but $\{Pg_n\}_n$ does not converge.

I am searching a domain where P is a continuous functional. My professor gave me the example 
$$D_P=\{\varphi \in L_2(0,2\pi):\varphi(0)=\varphi(2\pi) \}$$
but I'm not convinced because if I consider the function $\psi$

\begin{equation}
   \begin{cases}
   -\frac{x}{\sqrt{\pi}}+\sqrt{\pi},\hspace{0.5cm} 0\leq x<\pi\\\sqrt{x-\pi},\hspace{0.5cm} \pi\leq x \leq 2\pi
   \end{cases} 
\end{equation}
it belongs to $D_P$, but if I apply P on it I obtain

\begin{equation}
   \begin{cases}
   \frac{i}{\sqrt{\pi}},\hspace{0.5cm} 0\leq x<\pi\\ -\frac{i}{2\sqrt{x-\pi}},\hspace{0.5cm} \pi\leq x \leq 2\pi
   \end{cases} 
\end{equation}
that is not square-integrable on $(0,2\pi)$.

[image]

Am I wrong? If not, which is a correct continuity domain for P?

Comment: Cross-posted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/96583/2451